# Dualboot win10/Linux Mint boots directly into win10 - doesn't show grub

Tags: linux-mint, boot, windows, grub2, dual-boot

So I have a dual boot setup using Windows 10 and Linux Mint 17.2 but I can't boot into Mint normally because my laptop always boots into windows without showing grub.

In order to boot into Mint I have to hold F12 while booting, select my HDD and then select 'ubuntu' or 'Ubuntu' from a [list of items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvjQk.jpg), which brings me to [grub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekc5B.jpg). From there I can boot into windows and mint.

How do I fix this? Using boot-repair didn't work and neither did reinstalling Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 2):

use a live linux CD or DVD I suggest Ubuntu live and repair the grub or reinstall it.

mount the Mint partition to /mnt

and then:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda(the suitable based on your partition table)
```

check it with the below command to find your Mint partition:

```
fdisk -l
```

and then :

```
update-grub
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the fast response. ok I tried this and during `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/dev/sda8` it gives me the following error: `grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of '/cow'.
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install.real: error: install device isn't specified.`

Comment: And if I mount the boot partition to /mnt I can see a folder named 'ubuntu' inside `/mnt/dev/sda2/EFI`. What if I delete it and install everything again?

Comment: @NDTS  for the grub-probe error try this one :                                   mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc                                                         
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
grub-install /sd# yours seems 8
update-grub

Comment: OK so I fixed it by deleting the Ubuntu folder in /dev/sda2/EFI and then reinstalling grub with boot-repair from a live usb

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but I have observed that, if you don't turn off the fast boot feature of windows 10 before installing linux, these types of complications occur.